# Regex cut number in a string c#

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I have a string as following `2 - 5` now I want to get the number 5 with Regex C# (I'm new to Regex), could you suggest me an idea? Thanks

Comment: why not use string.Split('-') and then get the second element from the array ?

Comment: Why do you need regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `String.Split` method simply:

```
int number = int.Parse("2 - 5".Split('-', ' ').Last());
```

This will work if there is no space after the last number.If that is the case then:

```
 int number = int.Parse("2 - 5  ".Split('-', ' ')
              .Last(x => x.Any() && x.All(char.IsDigit)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simply as follows:

`'\s-\s(\d)'`

and extract first matching group

Answer (score 1):

@SShashank has the right of it, but I thought I'd supply some code, since you mentioned you were new to Regex:

```
string s = "something 2-5 another";
Regex rx = new Regex(@"-(\d)");
if (rx.IsMatch(s))
{
    Match m = rx.Match(s);
    System.Console.WriteLine("First match: " + m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Groups[0] is the entire match and Groups[1] is the first matched group (stuff in parens).

Comment: Thanks @James Jensen, could you please suggest me the idea when I have to take the string on the URL such as www.the-world-is-awesome.com I want to take the is-awesome in the URL and I tried with this pattern : @ "http: //www.the-world-(?<host>[A-Z-.]+).com" but it warns me an error in the pattern.

Comment: @user3520221: You need to escape the dashes and other metacharacters in the pattern if you want to match them verbatim.  Also, you need to make sure that the named match has the correct pattern as well.  For example, `http://www\.the\-world\-(?<host>.+)\.com` will match your example in a .NET Regex object and return "is-awesome".

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use regex, you can simply do:

```
string text = "2 - 5";

string found = Regex.Match(text, @"\d+", RegexOptions.RightToLeft).Value;
```